# Prove inequality $x_1+x_2-x_1x_2<1$ if $|x_1|<1$ and $|x_2|<1$

Tags: inequality

Also, the inequality $x_1+x_2+x_1x_2>-1$. I'm not sure how to elegantly approach this...Is there some existing inequality I can use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $$a+b-ab-1=(1-a)(b-1)$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $|x_1| < 1$ and $|x_2|<1$, we have $(1+s_1x_1)(1+s_2x_2) \geq 0$ for $s_1, s_2 \in \{-1,+1\}$. Use $s_1 = s_2 = -1$ to get the first inequality, and $s_1 = s_2 = +1$ for the other.